# align returns tuple instead of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, series

I am bit puzzled because I would expect the following code to produce a Pandas DataFrame or Series and instead returns a tuple.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import random
import pandas as pd

start_date = '2018-01-01'
end_date = '2018-06-06'
SPY = web.DataReader('SPY', 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
SPY = SPY[['Adj Close']]
SPY.columns = ['Price']

SPY1 = SPY.iloc[random.sample(range(len(SPY.index)), 80), ]
SPY2 = SPY.iloc[random.sample(range(len(SPY.index)), 80), ]

SPY3 = SPY1.align(SPY2, join = 'inner', axis = 0)

type(SPY3)
tuple
```

I can transform the tuple to a Series as follows:

```
SPY3 = pd.Series(SPY3[0])
```

Still I wonder why a tuple is returned in the first place.

Comment: Typical usage would be to reassign the co-aligned objects `SPY1_, SPY2_ = SPY1.align(SPY2, join='inner', axis=0)`.  In other words, the first element of the tuple is the aligned version of `SPY1` and the second element of the tuple is the aligned version of `SPY1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `align` returns a tuple according to [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html):

> **Returns: (left, right) : (DataFrame, type of other)**
>
> Aligned objects

`(left, right)` is a tuple

Comment: In `SPY1.align(SPY2, join = 'inner', axis = 0)` you say you want to align `SPY1` with `SPY2`. But according to the documentation `SPY2` can be of type Series or a Dataframe. The function align does not only return a Dataframe but also the **type** of `SPY2`. I do not know exactly what the reason is that they return the type. I think it is up to you what you want to do with the type information.